# Jquery selected value of highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make my editor where when you highlight text on your computer, jquery will take that selected value and throw the tags around it, more specificity code or pre tags.

```
    var Selectedvalue =  // set highlighted selection value
        $("#content").contents().find("body").append($("<pre></pre>").append(Selectedvalue))
   ;
```

I already know how to get the value between the tags, i just need to know how to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from googling of few time and found out http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html i am sure this is it.

[**Example**](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/05/get-selected-text-javascript.html)

**Response to OP comment**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        var ifx = $('<iframe src="code/sample.html" height=200 width=200></iframe>').appendTo(document.body);

        $(document.body).bind('mouseover', function()
        {
            var u_sel;
            if(window.getSelection)
            {
                u_sel = ifx[0].contentWindow.getSelection();
                alert(u_sel);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This is useful for future reference, but i forgot to mention it is for a iframe xD. Do you think you can help me on that one?

Comment: well i didn't tried it on my own but i added tested working code to my answer please set it according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
function getSelectionText() {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return text;
```

}